# Lightning close-channel transaction example?

Tags: lightning-network, script, ln-closing-channels, blockchain-explorer

From [this article](https://blog.chainside.net/understanding-payment-channels-4ab018be79d4), I can understand that a punishment-based bidirectional payment channel (the type used by Lightning) would contain roughly this bitcoin script as one of the outputs:

```
OP_IF
“+7 days” OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY OP_DROP
<Bob pubkey> OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ELSE
OP_SHA256 <sha256(Bob secret)> OP_EQUALVERIFY
<Alice pubkey> OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ENDIF
```

I guess there are some block explorers that let you visualize the real script being used in a transaction, so can anyone point me to a real LN transaction (in mainnet) that follows the template above?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual script implemented on Lightning Network is a little bit different from what you quoted. This is the script below and the specification is [here](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/03-transactions.md#to_local-output)

```
OP_IF
    # Penalty transaction
    <revocationpubkey>
OP_ELSE
    `to_self_delay`
    OP_CSV
    OP_DROP
    <local_delayedpubkey>
OP_ENDIF
OP_CHECKSIG
```

I've created that transaction on Testnet as the following,

Txid:
[4f8d776c85b1fc15c1125e7043a9aee70e33f0793b472823e3946a8de075bec4](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/4f8d776c85b1fc15c1125e7043a9aee70e33f0793b472823e3946a8de075bec4)

Rawdata:

```
6321026644cb387614f66421d14da3596c21cffa239011416c9adf3f351ee8551a9fc767029000b27521029654f80732769d7c435a184a3559f12178315526c53bbf003349390811c7590a68ac
```

Decoded by [here](http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/decodescript)

```
{
    "result": {
        "asm": "OP_IF 026644cb387614f66421d14da3596c21cffa239011416c9adf3f351ee8551a9fc7 OP_ELSE 144 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY OP_DROP 029654f80732769d7c435a184a3559f12178315526c53bbf003349390811c7590a OP_ENDIF OP_CHECKSIG",
        "type": "nonstandard",
        "p2sh": "35M7MGVGd3ajyiTMvriUiyUM3H2cT5sgb4"
    },
    "error": null,
    "id": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

blockchain.com has a "show scripts" link.

Here's a mainnet LN transaction:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/2facfe9147121b64761bef31c3808f43f92311349dbba01217bb666f0bd9b83c?show_adv=true

From this channel:
https://1ml.com/channel/586011110465142785

Comment: mmm but those scripts don't match the template I posted in my question

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `revocationpubkey` is derived https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/03-transactions.md#revocationpubkey-derivation